# How can I make this GeoGebra function work in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, pstricks

I am using geogebra to do some graphics of functions in LaTeX, but it is not giving me the same results. This is how de graphic looks like in GeoGebra:
[image: Geogebra graph]

Exporting the TikZ code, I get the image on top, exporting the PSTricks code I get the exact image I want (bottom)

[image: TikZ and PSTricks graph]

Usually I don't mind using PSTricks, but for this case I would rather not have to build the picture file separately. Does anyone know how do I get the shading part using the TikZ package??

P.S.: The code for this picture is too long for me to post here, sorry.

Comment: Please post the code and we won't be sorry.

Comment: @Werner https://github.com/lpeconick/TikZ/issues/1

Comment: Tip: A [gist](https://gist.github.com) might be a more convenient place for things like this, it's meant as a way of sharing single blocks of code.

Comment: You are better off not starting from that code if you need to edit it. Use `pgfplots` or redo the Ti*k*Z version. It is fine when exports give you usable-as-is code. But when they don't, the code is horrible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be a starting point where good users can edit and add what is missing.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{\pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[no markers, domain=0:10, samples=100,
axis lines*=left, xlabel=fghjfgj, ylabel=fdgjfjfj,
height=6cm, width=10cm,
xtick={-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3}, ytick=\empty,
enlargelimits=false, clip=false, axis on top]
\addplot[color=orange,line width=1.5pt, fill=cyan!20, domain=-2:2] {gauss(0,1)} \closedcycle;
\addplot [color=orange,line width=1.5pt, fill=white, domain=-3:-2] {gauss(0,1)} \closedcycle;
\addplot [color=orange,line width=1.5pt,fill=white, domain=2:3] {gauss(0,1)} \closedcycle;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```